# Scan for process and then kill it once found and start over

Tags: vb.net, process, kill

I'm trying to write a simple program that would check every 5 sec if a certain process is running and if it is, then kill it. The program should run in background and would be started every time the machine is started.
Its written in VB 
Process so far :

```
Module Module1
Private Declare Auto Function ShowWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Integer) As Boolean
Private Declare Auto Function GetConsoleWindow Lib "kernel32.dll" () As IntPtr
Private Const SW_HIDE As Integer = 0

Sub Main() 
eh:
    Dim hWndConsole As IntPtr
    hWndConsole = GetConsoleWindow()
    ShowWindow(hWndConsole, SW_HIDE)
    For Each proc As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("hl") 'hl is the process to look for
        proc.WaitForExit(5000) 'wait up to 5 seconds.
        proc.Kill() 'force the process to exit.

    Next proc
    GoTo eh
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000) 'Sleep for 5 sec and start over
End Sub
End Module
```

But the problem is, it shows console window everytime it starts and it also crashes after it kills the detected process

Answer (score -1):

Of course, because you try to search a process that you have already killed: `For Each proc As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("hl")`

Try something like that:

```
For Each prog As Process In Process.GetProcesses
    If prog.ProcessName = "hl" Then
            prog.Kill()
            Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for responce. I changed as you suggested, but it still crashes after it has killed the process and if the process should be restarted by user.

Comment: So.. first of all use `Try Catch` then you can better handle errors. And i suggest you to run this code in a `separate thread`.
After you have edit your code with the Try, let me know the error message.